# alter Jquery UI automcomplete combobox to normal combobox

Tags: jquery, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i use this example as a base:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

its cool. But if you type in something custom, after unfocus, the element vanish.

**i would like that the custom typed word stays there.**

This way you would have a "real" combobox. consisting of predefined suggestions AND a custom text input.

I dont search for plugins doing this, i really want to alter the ui code.

Using this [widget](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) i identified a remove event but i dont know how to access and prevent that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, i was so busy searching the ui.code that i did not analyse the code that generates the combobox

simply,
uncomment this

```
 if ( !valid ) {
                                        // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                        // $( this ).val( "" );
                                        select.val( "" );
                                        input.data( "autocomplete" ).term = "";


                return false;
```